# Изменение конфигурации приложения на Spring Boot во время работы

Tags: java, spring-boot

Можно ли изменить конфигурацию приложения или бина во время работы приложения? Или обновления конфигурации можно применить только при запуске/перезапуске?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы будете изменять код во время запущенного приложения, то никаких изменений не произойдет. Чтобы изменения вступили в силу, Вам необходимо перезапустить приложение. Поэтому ответ на Ваш вопрос: обновление конф. можно применить только при перезапуске.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы можете обновлять отдельные бины java конфигураций, а также конфигурацию.

У спринга существует проект [Spring Cloud](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html), благодаря которому вы можете централизованно управлять конфигурациями практически любых микросервисов (в том числе обновление конфигураций без редеплоя). Пометив аннтотацией **@RefreshScope** класс конфигураций вы можете управлять полями этой конфигурации, изменяя их на удаленном сервере конфигураций.

Из javadoc к аннотации **@RefreshScope**

```
Beans annotated this way can be refreshed at runtime and any components that
are using them will get a new instance on the next method call, fully
initialized and injected with all dependencies.
```